# Can i put css on a condition required in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know if there is a way to add css on a required element in JavaScript I have many condition and i want it just in this case i want something like that (I know i can't do this)
Thanks for your help !

```
  if (!allAreFilled) {                                          // While required element are empty
        alert('Fill all the fields');
        objForm.style:required.border = "solid 1px red";            // objForm = document.getElementById('compoundFormId')
      }
```

Comment: You could just [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a CSS class in a condition

Answer (score 1):

With [css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:required):

```
input:required {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Comment: I really need it from the Javascript after a condition

Comment: With required you should already get some red border or other styling right

Comment: I want it to be red only when we press the submit button

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly change CSS style settings for pseudo elements or classes in Javascript.

But you can set CSS variables from JS.

This snippet sets a CSS variable `--border` when the submit button is clicked with the value depending on a condition.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let conditionIsSet = true;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--border', (conditionIsSet) ? 'red' : 'black');
});
```

```css
body {
  --border: black;
}

input:required {
  border: var(--border) 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="conditionIsSet = !conditionIsSet;">Select condition is true</input>
<br> Input without required: <input> Input with required: <input required>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Obviously you need to supply whatever condition is needed.